# How do I configure Xceed Real-Time for .NET compression to allow non-ascii file names?

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage, compression, xceed, real-time-data

What I'm trying to do is to compress files in real-time as they're coming down in chunks from Azure Blob Storage, and then stream the compressed chunks immediately down to the browser.  Everything works perfectly except the ability to allow non-ascii characters in the file names.  The Xceed compression utility strips the files out.  How would I set the real-time ZipWriter to allow for these non-ascii characters in file names?  The recommendation is to use "ExtraHeaders", however, that property is in a different namespace (Xceed.Zip vs. the ZipWriter which is in Xceed.Zip.ReaderWriter namespace).  Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Xceed Real-Time already automatically adds the necessary extra header information to allow for non-ascii characters. The problem is that Windows Explorer in Windows 7 is unable to deal with non-ascii characters. It works in Windows 8, however.